# When are the roots of a polynomial of degree 3 aligned?

Tags: geometry, polynomials, cubics

Let $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree 3. On what condition on the coefficients of $P$ are the three roots of $P$ aligned ?

To make things easier, we may assume that $P$ can be written as $P = X^3 + aX^2 + bX + c$.

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ be the roots of $P$.

I tried to say that the condition was $\Im((a - c) \overline{(b - c)}) = 0$, but I could not manage to get anywhere. Trying to write $z_3 = k z_1 + (1 - k) z_2$ ($k \in [0, 1]$) did not help me either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The derivative of

$$P(x)=x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c \tag{1}$$

is

$P'(x)= 3x^2+2ax+b \tag{2}$

Its two roots are

$$z'_k=\frac13(-a\pm d) \ \ \text{where} \ d:=\sqrt{a^2-3b}\tag{3}$$

(the square root that has to be taken in the complex sense).

These roots are known to be inside triangle $z_1z_2z_3$ ([Gauss-Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem)).

The alignment of $z_1,z_2,z_3$ is therefore necessarily along the line $L$ defined by $[z'_1,z'_2]$ which can be described as the following set of points:

$$z=\lambda z'_1+(1-\lambda) z'_2= - \ \frac{a}{3}+\frac13(2 \lambda d -1)\tag{4}$$

where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now plug relationship (4) into (1).

Remark: a supplementary condition is the fact that two of the roots must lie ouside open segment $(z'_1,z'_2)$, implying that $0<\lambda<1$ can happen for at most one root.

Comment: I had thought about Lucas' theorem, but I could not manage to see how to use it. Thank you anyway, I will be trying to find the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am already back, but I have been working on this problem for the past last hour, and I coult not figure it out ... I can not see how I can use your hint: once again, should I write $z_1$ with the roots of $P’$ ? Should I use the imaginary parts as I was first suggesting with $P$ ?

Comment: Using [Marden's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem), the Steiner in-ellipse will have zero minor axis.  Refer to my post (but with different denotation) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603162/geometric-meaning-of-complex-cubic-polynomial-coefficients/2763171#2763171), the modulus of  the resolvents $u$ and $v$ are equal.

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak Excellent remark : why I hadn't thought to it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, Using resolvent means almost solving the equation but it's useful as parameter.  Personally, I prefer to use resolvents to *'parametrize'* a (reduced) cubic, de Moivre quintic, etc for studying their (geometric) properties.

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak maybe this paper has an interest for you: https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01104612/document

Answer (score 1):

(*Not an answer, but too long for a comment. Prompted by comments under this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458632/is-this-statement-about-roots-of-polynomials-well-known/).*)

For an $\,n^{th}\,$ degree polynomial with $\,n \ge 3\,$, the question whether its roots lie on a line in the complex plane relates to the question of determining whether the roots of an associated polynomial are all real.

If the roots of $\,n^{th}\,$ degree $\,P(z)\,$ are collinear, then the roots of all its derivatives must also lie on the same line by the [Gauss–Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem#Formal_statement).

Taking some liberty in assuming that all roots are distinct, it follows that the line on which all roots lie is the line through the two roots $\,a,b\,$ of the quadratic $\,P^{(n-2)}(z)=0\,$. That line can be mapped onto the real axis with a translation and/or rotation, so a necessary condition for the roots of $\,P(z)\,$ to be collinear is for all roots of $\,Q(z) = P(\omega z) - \nu\,$ to be real, for the respective $\,\omega, \nu \in \mathbb C\,$, with $\,|\omega|=1\,$, both of which can be explicitly determined from $\,a,b\,$.

In the case $\,n=3\,$ of a cubic, the quadratic in question is $\,P'(z)\,$, and that case is covered nicely in Jean Marie's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4150917/291201).