# Question related to ellipse inscribed in right angle triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

[image]

This question corresponds to an ellipse , the angle of triangle are $60^°,30^° ,90^°$. I tried to use the formula that product of distance drawn perpendicular to major axis from focus to the tangent is equal to $b^2$ if $a>b$ and ellipse is $*\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, but not able to proceed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints only**

- The ellipse with maximum area is [Steiner inellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_inellipse).
- Use [Marden's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem) to find out the foci.

> Let the cubic be $$z(z-1)(z-i\sqrt{3})=0$$

See also another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603162/geometric-meaning-of-complex-cubic-polynomial-coefficients/2763171#2763171) of mine for your interests.

**Further points**

- Family of inscribed ellipse bounded by the axes and line $\dfrac{x}{a}+\dfrac{y}{b}=1$ is given by $$
  \left(
    \frac{x}{\lambda a}+\frac{y}{\mu b}-1
  \right)^2=\frac{4xy}{ab}
  \left(
    \frac{1}{\lambda}-1
  \right)
  \left(
    \frac{1}{\mu}-1
  \right)
  $$ where $\lambda,\mu \in (0,1)$.
- Area of the ellipse is $$\frac{\pi \lambda \mu ab}{2} \sqrt{\frac{(1-\lambda)(1-\mu)}{(\lambda+\mu-\lambda \mu)^3}}$$

Comment: I like it, but is this really intendent solution? I don't believe it was. There must be more elementary solution.

Comment: I've added a family of inscribed ellipse in **further points** as reference.